# PHP: access a parent's static variable from an extended class' method

Tags: php, class, oop, variables, static

Still trying to figure out oop in PHP5. The question is, how to access a parent's static variable from an extended class' method. Example below.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class config {
    public static $base_url = 'http://example.moo';
}
class dostuff extends config {
   public static function get_url(){
      echo $base_url;
    }
}
 dostuff::get_url();
?>
```

I thought this would work from experience in other languages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's completely irrelevant that the property is declared in the parent, you access it the way you access *any* static property:

```
self::$base_url
```

or

```
static::$base_url  // for late static binding
```

Comment: Thanks. (rewriting comment, the previous ones didn't make sense) Can you access a static property declared in Child class, used in Parent class (late static binding), from another class, naming the Parent class, like in `Another` doing `Parent::Prop` (this doesn't work, but is there a way, doing some kind of late-static-binding-polymorphism)?

Comment: This makes no sense.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible, but actually should be written like this:

```
class dostuff extends config {
   public static function get_url(){
      echo parent::$base_url;
    }
}
```

But in this case you can access it both with `self::$base_url` and `static::$base_url` - as you don't redeclare this property in the extending class. Have you done it so, there would have been a distinction:

- `self::$base_url` would always refer to the property in the same class that line's written,
- `static::$base_url` to the property of the class the object belongs to (so called 'late static binding').

Consider this [example](https://eval.in/80904):

```
class config {
  public static $base_url = 'http://config.example.com';
  public function get_self_url() {
    return self::$base_url;
  }
  public function get_static_url() {
    return static::$base_url;
  }
}
class dostuff extends config {
  public static $base_url = 'http://dostuff.example.com';
}

$a = new config();
echo $a->get_self_url(), PHP_EOL;
echo $a->get_static_url(), PHP_EOL; // both config.example.com

$b = new dostuff();
echo $b->get_self_url(), PHP_EOL;   // config.example.com
echo $b->get_static_url(), PHP_EOL; // dostuff.example.com
```

Comment: I will upvote this when I have the rep. The other answer is cleaner because it avoids calling parents of parents when inheritance is a long chain.

Comment: Thank you for your examples. I learned about late static binding.